# Solution of first order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone please help me how to find the solution for:
$$ 
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=(x-5y)^{\frac{1}{3}}+ \frac{1}{5}.
$$
I found the singular curve for it, which is $y=\dfrac{x}{5}$ (please correct me if I'm wrong), but I can not find the family of solution for it. I tried every method that I know.
Please help me.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if 
\begin{align}
u:= x-5y
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx} = 1- 5\frac{dy}{dx}.
\end{align}
Using this fact, we can rewrite the differential equation as
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{5}\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{5}\left(1-5\frac{dy}{dx} \right) =\frac{1}{5}-\frac{dy}{dx} = -(x-5y)^{1/3} =-u^{1/3}.
\end{align}
Hence we have a separable equation.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=(x-5y)^{\frac{1}{3}}+ \frac{1}{5}.$$
$$5y'=5(x-5y)^{\frac{1}{3}}+1$$
$$-(1-5y')=5(x-5y)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
You observe that the derivative of $x-5y$ is just $1-5y'$

$$\int \frac {d(x-5y)}{(x-5y)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=-5\int dx$$

It's easy to solve now
$$ \frac 32{(x-5y)^{\frac{2}{3}}}=-5x+K$$